# How do I manipulate the icon for an existing desktop shortcut using Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, shortcut-file

I want to be able to get the current .ico file being used for a shortcut and then change it to a different .ico file temporarily. I was planning on parsing the .lnk files manually, but I thought I might ask for an easier way here first.

Comment: [IShellLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @JonathanPotter How do I get the index of an icon loaded through `LoadImage`?

Comment: You have to know the index beforehand so you can tell `LoadImage()` what to load. Why do you need `LoadImage()` at all? That is a different question than what you originally asked. You don't need `LoadImage()` in order to change a `.lnk` file's icon.

Comment: [Shell Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to use custom .ico files instead of the system resources. e.g. `LoadImageW( NULL, path.c_str( ), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT | LR_DEFAULTSIZE ) `

Comment: Your call to `LoadImage` implies, that you are trying to load an icon from disk. In that case, you don't need that at all. Just use the information provided above, and read the helpful links. Unless the question you asked is not what you meant to ask.

Comment: You do not need `LoadImage()` to update a `.lnk` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950.aspx) interface.  Here are examples from MSDN:

[Shell Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx)

```
// CreateLink - Uses the Shell's IShellLink and IPersistFile interfaces 
//              to create and store a shortcut to the specified object. 
//
// Returns the result of calling the member functions of the interfaces. 
//
// Parameters:
// lpszPathObj  - Address of a buffer that contains the path of the object,
//                including the file name.
// lpszPathLink - Address of a buffer that contains the path where the 
//                Shell link is to be stored, including the file name.
// lpszDesc     - Address of a buffer that contains a description of the 
//                Shell link, stored in the Comment field of the link
//                properties.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winnls.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres;
```

```
// ResolveIt - Uses the Shell's IShellLink and IPersistFile interfaces 
//             to retrieve the path and description from an existing shortcut. 
//
// Returns the result of calling the member functions of the interfaces. 
//
// Parameters:
// hwnd         - A handle to the parent window. The Shell uses this window to 
//                display a dialog box if it needs to prompt the user for more 
//                information while resolving the link.
// lpszLinkFile - Address of a buffer that contains the path of the link,
//                including the file name.
// lpszPath     - Address of a buffer that receives the path of the link
                  target, including the file name.
// lpszDesc     - Address of a buffer that receives the description of the 
//                Shell link, stored in the Comment field of the link
//                properties.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"
#include "strsafe.h"

HRESULT ResolveIt(HWND hwnd, LPCSTR lpszLinkFile, LPWSTR lpszPath, int iPathBufferSize) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 
    WCHAR szGotPath[MAX_PATH]; 
    WCHAR szDescription[MAX_PATH]; 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd; 

    *lpszPath = 0; // Assume failure 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called. 
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Get a pointer to the IPersistFile interface. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszLinkFile, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Load the shortcut. 
            hres = ppf->Load(wsz, STGM_READ); 

            if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
            { 
                // Resolve the link. 
                hres = psl->Resolve(hwnd, 0); 

                if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                { 
                    // Get the path to the link target. 
                    hres = psl->GetPath(szGotPath, MAX_PATH, (WIN32_FIND_DATA*)&wfd, SLGP_SHORTPATH); 

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                    { 
                        // Get the description of the target. 
                        hres = psl->GetDescription(szDescription, MAX_PATH); 

                        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
                        {
                            hres = StringCbCopy(lpszPath, iPathBufferSize, szGotPath);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
                            {
                                // Handle success
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Handle the error
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } 

            // Release the pointer to the IPersistFile interface. 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 

        // Release the pointer to the IShellLink interface. 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}
```

In your case, you would:

1. Create an instance of `IShellLink`
2. query it for `IPersistFile()`
3. call `IPersistFile.Load()` to set the `.lnk` filename
4. call `IShellLink.Resolve()` to load the file
5. call `IShellLink.SetIconLocation()` to set a new `.ico` filename
6. Call `IPersistFile.Save()` to save the new `.lnk` file.

Comment: @RemyLeabeau It worked. One more thing though, how should I handle a COM error? Should I just use `GetLastError( )` and `FormatMessage( )` or do I have to handle it based on the codes returned by the COM interface?

Comment: COM does not use `GetLastError()`. `HRESULT` contains the error code, if any.  You can pass system-defined `HRESULT` values (such as those whose facility is `FACILITY_WIN32`) to `FormatMessage()`, but custom `HRESULT` values (those whose facility is `FACILITY_ITF`) cannot. If a COM object implements [`ISupportErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221083.aspx), you can retrieve [`IErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233.aspx) via [`GetErrorInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032.aspx).