# Give a shortcut an icon

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an "installer" for my exe program in C++, but what I want the program to do is, create a program that makes a shortcut from the exe file, and then goes into an images folder and use an image.ico to set the newly made shortcuts image to be that of image.ico I really don't have any ideas on how to do this

Comment: I am assuming you're on Windows. What are you working with? Qt? WinAPI? Something else? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically create a shortcut using Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906974/how-to-programmatically-create-a-shortcut-using-win32) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665476/how-do-i-manipulate-the-icon-for-an-existing-desktop-shortcut-using-win32).

Comment: On Windows, if you use `IShellLink` to create the shortcut then you can use the `IShellLink::SetIconLocation()` method to specify an icon file for the shortcut.

Comment: ah cool that works thanks